# Serialize list using javascript serializer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, serialization

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I'm currently calling a list of countries in my database and for each country in the list, I'm wanting to create an option to select from. I initially hardcoded the list in my JS script and had it working great, but wanted to try calling the list of countries from the DB instead. So the following questions I have are:

1)Is using javascript serializer the best method for getting the list of countries and creating an option for each country in the list?

2)If so, how can I get the correct format to display? Right now I'm serializing the list, but it's creating a new option for each character instead of each string. Is there a way to specify the delimiter?

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Dim jsonSerialiser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "fillCountry('" + jsonSerialiser.Serialize(CustomerFactory.GetCountry) + "');", True)
End If
```

Here's the script

```
function fillCountry (countListProp) {
    var countryElement = document.getElementById('countryId');
    countryElement.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < countListProp.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[i] = new Option(countListProp[i]);
    }
}
```